# Match multiple strings in a textual template

Tags: c#, regex

This might be a trivial question for experienced Regex experts, but after searching for hours, I have to admit that I don't seem to know the right search terms.

I faintly remember that in some search/replace targeted regex engines (text editors) it is possible to define variables for subpattern matches in order to rearrange them in the replacement string. Something like (pseudo-code)

```
string input = "name: john, profession: lumberjack";
string pattern = @"[a-z]*: %1=([a-z]*), [a-z]*: %2=([a-z]*)";
string replacement = @"customer %1 is a %2";
string result = Regex.Replace(input ,pattern ,replacement);
```

where result should assume "customer john is a lumberjack". I don't know if that is possible in C#, but what I would rather like to do is to get the subpattern matches returned in an array, like (again pseudo-code)

```
string[] subMatches = Regex.MultiMatch(input ,pattern);
```

where `subMatches[0]=="john"` and `subMatches[1]=="lumberjack"`.

I know that I can do it on a match-by-match basis with [lookaround assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and, in a loop, construct the array and check whether all sub-patterns match.

But is there also a single-line expression (like the second code block above) for what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pushing me into the right direction, towards Groups. Wiktor has answered the first part of the question, regarding replacement. As to the second part (getting the group matches in a string array), I have come up with the following solution

```
string input = "name: john, profession: lumberjack";
string pattern = @"[a-z]+:\s*([a-z]+),\s*[a-z]+:\s*([a-z]+)";

string[] subMatches = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups
    .Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
        
foreach (string s in subMatches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output:

> john
>
> lumberjack

The cast is necessary because Linq doesn't seem to be prepared to deal with GroupCollections. Skip is necessary because the very first group match is the whole pattern, whereas the subsequent items in the GroupCollection are the matches of the individual groups.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a simple regex with capturing groups and a `Regex.Replace` with replacement backreferences (placeholders) to insert the submatches:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"[a-z]+:\s*([a-z]+),\s*[a-z]+:\s*([a-z]+)", "customer $1 is a $2");
// => customer john is a lumberjack
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fv86fp/1/)

**Pattern details**

- `[a-z]+` - 1+ lowercase ASCII letters (to match any letters, use `\p{L}` and to use any "word" chars, use `\w` instead of `[a-z]`)
- `:\s*`  - a colon followed with 0+ whitespace chars
- `([a-z]+)` - Group 1 (referenced to using `$1` from the replacement pattern): 1+ ASCII lowercase letters (see note above)
- `,\s*` - a comma and 0+ whitespace chars
- `[a-z]+:\s*` - 1+ ASCII lowercase letters, `:` and 0+ whitespace chars
- `([a-z]+)` - Group 2 (referenced to using `$2` from the replacement pattern): 1+ ASCII lowercase letters (see note above)

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor, and what about the string array version? Can it be done with Match.Groups? Could there be any interference with other possible applications of groups?

Comment: @oliver I do not think you need to solve the real problem in another way, `Regex.Replace` is the method that is meant to *replace*, *rearrange*, *modify* the input string by searching for matches and replacing them with a replacement pattern. If you want to use a dictionary for replacements, it is also possible. If you need to extract that information, you may use `Regex.Matches(s, @"my_regex").Cast<Match>().Select(x=>new { x.Groups[1].Value, x.Groups[2].Value})`